# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (150,150) into shape (28,28) - cv2.resize() weird error

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, scikit-image

I am trying to upscale the MNIST handwritten digit images before training. But both cv2.resize() and skimage.transform.resize throws : ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (150,150) into shape (28,28)

```
    for i in range(len(X_train)):
      X_train[i] = resize(X_train[i], (150,150))
```

Comment: What's the full error message?  I suspect the error is in the `X[i]=...` assignment, not the `resize`.  What's the `shape` of `X_train`?

Comment: What happens if you execute `tmp = resize(X_train[i], (150,150))`

Comment: aahh! Now I get the issue!  'tmp = resize(X_train[0], (150,150))' runs perfectly. As X_train is of shape(60000,28,28,1) the assignement was causing the error. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Aahh! Now I get the issue! 
'tmp = resize(X_train[0], (150,150))' 
runs perfectly. As X_train is of shape(60000,28,28,1) so the assignement was causing the error.